# Failed to get type for: content://

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, file-get-contents, android-9.0-pie

In Nougat and Pie, this function is not working. I have used below function to get realpath form content uri for .mp3 files. Please check below link:

[Get Real File Path From Android Uri](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-get-real-file-path-from-android-uri/)

**Error log:**

*2019-07-01 14:39:33.965 9971-10277/com.mp3musicapp W/ContentResolver: Failed to get type for: content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1 (Unknown URL : content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1)

2019-07-01 14:39:33.971 9971-10278/com.mp3musicapp W/ContentResolver: Failed to get type for: content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1 (Unknown URL : content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1)*

Above function couldn't work properly, I have try it but not working proper in Android Pie and couldn't find any solution. **So Please help me.**

Comment: you cannot get any real path for your `Uri` - what do you want to achieve actually with given `Uri`?

Comment: I want to get real path from content uri.

Comment: because `Uri` != `File` you cannot get any **real path** from `Uri` - more: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html

Comment: Hello, I have content uri not a file uri - content://media/external/audio/albumart/-1. Now I'm getting realpath form content uri using above method (link mention in question). But getting error like - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist. Available columns: []". So what I do dear.

Comment: in the link i posted you have the section saying: *"Ideally, nowadays, those Uri values are “openable”. You can perform the following operations on such Uri values:"* - read it carefully

Comment: Hello, I want to play this uri in my musiv player. Is it possible to play in all Android version. "content://cn.xender.provider/external_files/Music/90s%20Bollywood%20Songs%20Mashup.mp3"

Comment: you mean `MediaPlayer` class?

Comment: yes. I want to play this uri in MediaPlayer class.

Comment: and how do you create a new `MediaPlayer` instance? with `MediaPlayer.create` static method?

Comment: I got a new path as per above link: "/data/user/0/com.sahajanand.mp3musicapp/files/90s Bollywood Songs Mashup.mp3"

Media Player Code:
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();

Comment: yes, `setDataSource` is what you should use

Comment: in setDataSource I'm use below path:

"Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Uri.fromFile(new File(videoRealPath)).toString());"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195834/discussion-between-sumit-pansuriya-and-pskink).